# How to use a StaggeredGridView with dynamic length?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I'm using `flutter_staggered_grid_view` package.

I have this:

```
List<StaggeredTile> _staggeredTiles = const <StaggeredTile>[
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(2, 2),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(2, 2),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
];
```

If you'll count the number of items, it has **18**. Now, I'm fetching my images from the server and its length is dynamic.

If the length is greater than the number of items declared in my `_staggeredTiles`, all 18 images will show and the rest of the images won't show in the page and will give a **Range Error**.

Anyone used this package? How can I reuse my `_staggeredTiles` if the length of my images exceeds the length of `_staggeredTiles`?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hey  the accepted answer helped @Gentle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `StaggeredGridView.countBuilder` 
**Edit** 
and create a `Map` then use math `mod` 18 to map key to your value

code snippet

```
Map<int, int> tileMap = {
    0: 1,
    1: 2,
    2: 1,
    3: 1,
    4: 1,
    5: 1,
    6: 1,
    7: 1,
    8: 1,
    9: 2,
    10: 1,
    11: 1,
    12: 1,
    13: 1,
    14: 1,
    15: 1,
    16: 1,
    17: 1
  }; 

 staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
        new StaggeredTile.count(tileMap[index % 18], tileMap[index % 18]),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class StaggeredGridExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StaggeredGridExampleState createState() => _StaggeredGridExampleState();
}

class _StaggeredGridExampleState extends State<StaggeredGridExample> {
  Map<int, int> tileMap = {
    0: 1,
    1: 2,
    2: 1,
    3: 1,
    4: 1,
    5: 1,
    6: 1,
    7: 1,
    8: 1,
    9: 2,
    10: 1,
    11: 1,
    12: 1,
    13: 1,
    14: 1,
    15: 1,
    16: 1,
    17: 1
  };

  final List<String> images = [
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=1",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=2",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=3",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=4",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=5",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=6",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=7",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=8",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=10",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=11",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=12",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=13",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=14",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=15",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=16",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=17",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=18",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=19",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=20",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        itemCount: images.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
          child: FittedBox(
            child: Image.network(images[index]),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
        staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
            new StaggeredTile.count(tileMap[index % 18], tileMap[index % 18]),
        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: StaggeredGridExample(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to make it look like Instagram's search page. The pattern I made is similar to it.

Comment: I have update my answer. you can do it with Map and math mod tileMap[index % 18]

Comment: hey@chunhunghan

Comment: can you help me out to manage staggered with json data like different row for each column